# How to accept a wrkprofile device in google console?

Tags: android-work-profile

I am registering to new work profile as my old phone broke, but i can use it to transfer data/OPTs/authenticator. Now with admin privileges in hand how can I activate my own new device? Any pointers in the google console are appreciated.